# How to get Max String Length in every Column of a Datatable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, max

I have a DataTable object. Every column is of type string.

Using LINQ, how can I get the maximum string length for every column?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The maximum string length for the whole table:

```
int? maxStringLength = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .SelectMany(row => row.ItemArray.OfType<string>())
    .Max(str => str?.Length);
```

If you want maximum string length for **each** column, you could do:

```
List<int?> maximumLengthForColumns = 
   Enumerable.Range(0, dataTable.Columns.Count)
       .Select(col => dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(row => row[col]).OfType<string>()
            .Max(val => val?.Length)
       ).ToList();
```

Comment: That gets the length of the longest string in the whole table.
I need the lengths of the longest strings in every column.

Answer (score 2):

With c# 6, you can prevent the exception by adding val?.Length

```
var maximumLengthForColumns =
                Enumerable.Range(0, dt.Columns.Count)
                .Select(col => dt.AsEnumerable()
                                     .Select(row => row[col]).OfType<string>()
                                     .Max(val => val?.Length )).ToList();
```

Comment: Don't you mean IEnumerable? Enumerable is undefined in C#

Comment: Code from @roncansan works great. However how can I get {ColumnName, MaxLength}  pair in the "var maximumLengthForColumns"? OR Is it "Guranteed" that  the MaxLength values in the  "var maximumLengthForColumns" will be in exact order of the Columns in the table. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consider maxLength for each column of table with multi line cell value. I have created one that return Dictionary<Column-Index, MaxLength>

[image]

```
    private Dictionary<int, int> TableColumnWidth(DataTable dt)
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> result = new();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            int maxLength = 0;
            int cellLength = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (row[i] != DBNull.Value && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[i].ToString())) 
                {
                    cellLength = row[i].ToString().Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Max(x => x.Length);
                    if (maxLength < cellLength) 
                    {
                        maxLength= cellLength;
                    }
                }
            }
            result.Add(i, maxLength);
        }
    return result;
}
```