# Get the max length for each field of a DataTable

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable, translate

My goal is to show the whole content of a `DataTable` into a `RichTextBox` so I thought about using `String.Format` to make columns but I need to know the max length of contents for each Column.

I found the below C# code on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053560/how-to-get-max-string-length-in-every-column-of-a-datatable) but I was unable to translate it to VB.Net:

```
List<int> maximumLengthForColumns = Enumerable.Range(0, dataTable.Columns.Count)
                                   .Select(col => dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                   .Select(row => row[col]).OfType<string>()
                                   .Max(val => val.Length)).ToList();
```

Any hint on any different (and easier or better) way to reach my goal is appreciated.

Comment: Which language do you want to use, c# or VB.NET?

Comment: @Takarii I want to use vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'dtb is the datatable'
Dim lstMaxLen As New List(Of Integer)
For Each dcl As DataColumn In dtb.Columns
  Dim intMaxLen As Integer = 0
  For Each drw As DataRow In dtb.Rows
    If drw(dcl.ColumnName).ToString.Length > intMaxLen Then
      intMaxLen = drw(dcl.ColumnName).ToString.Length
    End If
  Next drw
  lstMaxLen.Add(intMaxLen)
Next dcl
```

Comment: Or you could use a datagridview and autosize the columns

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
Dim maximumLengthForColumns As List(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(0, DataTable.Columns.Count).[Select](Function(col) dataTable.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(row) row(col)).OfType(Of String)().Max(Function(val) val.Length)).ToList()
```

The formatted code is as below(*this one is just for readability*):

```
Dim maximumLengthForColumns As List(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(0, dataTableDataTable.Columns.Count)
                                                 .[Select](Function(col) dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                                 .[Select](Function(row) row(col))
                                                 .OfType(Of String)().Max(Function(val) val.Length)).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I get error on `.[Select]` and (if I turn on `Option Strict`) on `Enumerable.Range(0, dataTable.Columns.Count)` because of a conversion from `IEnumerable(Of Integer)` to a `List(Of Integer)`

Comment: @genespos...Paste the code without line breaks. I used line breaks to more readability you should copy this code: `Dim maximumLengthForColumns As List(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(0, DataTable.Columns.Count).[Select](Function(col) dataTable.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(row) row(col)).OfType(Of String)().Max(Function(val) val.Length)).ToList()`

Comment: Thanks! Now the syntax is right but I noticed that the code seems to work only on fields of `String` while I have both `String` and `Double` fields. Is there any way to make the code works also on fields of type `Double`?

Comment: @genespos...This works only on fields of String because you wrote `OfType(Of String)`. If you want the code works with both types then you may have a look at `Generic`.

Comment: Thanks. You were really helpful (+1)