# Max String Length in every Column of a Datatable in VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable

I need to know the maximum current lenght of each column of a DataTable (using VB.Net)
I need the maximum `.ToString.Length` for each column.

I found the below C# code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053560/how-to-get-max-string-length-in-every-column-of-a-datatable), but I wasn't able to translate it to VB.Net

```
List<int> maximumLengthForColumns = 
   Enumerable.Range(0, dataTable.Columns.Count)
             .Select(col => dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                     .Select(row => row[col]).OfType<string>()
                                     .Max(val => val.Length)).ToList();
```

**EDIT**
I finally was able to translate the code in more readable vb.net but not to adapt it to my needs:

```
maximumLengthForColumns = Enumerable.Range(0, DT.Columns.Count).
    Select(Function(col)
               Return DT.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(row)
                                                   Return row(col)
                                               End Function).OfType(Of String)().Max(Function(v)
                                                                                         Return v.Length
                                                                                     End Function)
           End Function).ToList()
```

Comment: you should be able to translate that by just typing the same words in VB.  For newlines, leave the dot on the previous line.

Comment: Have you tried using an on-line C# to VB converter?

Comment: @Plutonix I've tried on one line this way (but it gives me errors): `Dim maximumLengthForColumns As List(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(0, DT_IntCalc.Columns.Count).Select(col >= DT_IntCalc.AsEnumerable().Select(row >= row[col]).OfType(Of String).Max(Val() >= Val.Length)).ToList()`

Comment: ahh, the trick is that `=>` in C# translates to the wordy `Function (q) ...` where `q` would be `row`, `val` or `col` in the code.  dont use val though, use `v`

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks, I've got this (no errors -> I'm testing it): `Dim maximumLengthForColumns As List(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(0, dataTable.Columns.Count).[Select](Function(col) dataTable.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(row) row(col)).OfType(Of String)().Max(Function(val) val.Length)).ToList()`

Comment: You ought never use code you dont understand - you could just as easily loop thru the DT to get the answer.

Comment: @Plutonix I think you're right (as ever) but I've learned all I know starting from unknown code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted self answer is iterating all columns and treating them like string columns even if they are not.  That is, it is measuring and collecting the `.ToString` length of Data which is not string (which seems not to be what's desired).

The non string datacolumns could be omitted this way:

```vb
Dim MaxColLen As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
For Each dc As DataColumn In dtSample.Columns
    If dc.DataType Is GetType(String) Then
        MaxColLen.Add(dc.ColumnName, 0)
        For Each dr As DataRow In dtSample.Rows
            If dr.Field(Of String)(dc.ColumnName).Length > MaxColLen(dc.ColumnName) Then
                MaxColLen(dc.ColumnName) = dr.Field(Of String)(dc.ColumnName).Length
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Note that it uses `For Each` to reduce the clutter in code and allow the use of `DataRow` extensions such as `Field<T>()`. Personally, I think `Field(Of T)(Col)` is more readable than `DT.Rows(x)(Col).ToString` although if you **do** actually want to measure non string data, using it on non text data will surely crash.

Note that the loop skips over non string columns.  To find the longest text in 715,000 rows, the original takes ~34 ms, while the above takes ~9 ms.

A linqy version of the same dictionary approach (with comments explaining the steps):

```vb
' a) look at cols as cols
' b) just the string ones
' c) get the name and inital zed value to an Anonymous type
' d) convert to a dictionary of String, Int to store the longest
Dim txtCols = dtSample.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn).
                Where(Function(c) c.DataType = GetType(String)).
                Select(Function(q) New With {.Name = q.ColumnName, .Length = 0}).
                ToDictionary(Of String, Int32)(Function(k) k.Name, Function(v) v.Length)

' get keys into an array to interate
'  collect the max length for each 
For Each colName As String In txtCols.Keys.ToArray
    txtCols(colName) = dtSample.AsEnumerable().
            Max(Function(m) m.Field(Of String)(colName).Length)
Next
```

This form takes ~12 ms for the same 715k rows.  Extension methods are almost always slower, but the none of these differences are worth worrying about.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation (I'm starting to understand lambda expressions). I don't know if it's because of my english or simply I wasn't able to fully explain what I was looking for, but what I need is exactly the `ToString.Length` . I need this length because I need to show the content of the datatable into a `richtextbox` and I've thought about using `String.Format("{0, Col0Width} {1,Col1Width} ...{n,ColnWidth}",...)`.
I've tested the posted code on non string columns and it worked without errors; why do you think it will crash? Is there anything I haven't considered?

Comment: No, *your* `rows(r)(col).ToString` wont crash, the alternative `dr.Field(Of T)` version will crash trying using `Of String` on a non string column.  To get the text extent of all columns in the linqy version (#2), leave off the WHERE DataType line, and use `m(colName).ToString().Length`  in the loop.  The c# you posted in the OP is only checking string columns (`.OfType<string>()`) and thats what led everyone to believe you wanted to just test string lengths.

Answer (score 2):

A `DataTable` exposes a `Columns` property which is a collection of column definitions. Each item (which really is a `DataColumn` type) exposes the ***maximum allowable length***. The code sample that you found only looks at the data as stored in the table. That is, it is returning the ***current maximum length used*** by data, not the maximum supported by the column.

To retrieve the maximum allowed length, simply scan through the DataColumns property of the supplied DataTable object and use the `MaxLength` property.

Here's a snippet using LINQ syntax:

```
Dim maximumLengthForColumns = From c in dataTable.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)
        Order By c.Ordinal
        Select c.MaxLength
```

The actual type of this isn't exactly a List. It's `IQueryable(Of Integer)`. Ycan use `.ToList()` to force the enumeration and conversion instead of letting it sit idle until you actually need to use the results. You could just leave as an IQueryable if you just need to enumerate over the results as the interface does inherit from IEnumerable.

I didn't need to include an Order By clause. It will probably slow down the actual execution. But, if you have so many columns in your data table that this becomes a real bottleneck, you need to be taken out back and given some other remedial instruction.

Why didn't I add a filtering clause (`Select`)? The `MaxLength` property is exposed for all columns, not just string types. And, a simple enumeration of the results should probably match up to the number of columns in your original data table. If not, feel free to add the clause to the LINQ statement.

```
Where c.DataType = GetType(String)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the current Length of each column and not the maximum allowed length.

Answer (score 0):

You have to also translate those lambdas:

```
Dim maximumLengthForColumns As List(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(0, dataTable.Columns.Count).Select(Function(col) dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(row) row(col)).OfType(Of String)().Max(Function(val) val.Length)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-LINQ answer...

```
Dim maximumLengthForColumns As New List(Of Integer)
For i As Integer = 0 To dtb.Columns.Count - 1
  maximumLengthForColumns.Add(dtb.Columns(i).MaxLength)
Next i
```

If the size of the column is unlimited, then the `MaxLength` property returns `-1`

Comment: Thanks, but I need the current Length of each column and not the maximum allowed length.

Answer (score 0):

I was forced to do as @Putonix said and use a loop over the datatable for two reasons:

1) I wasn't able to use the translated `C#` code, because it gives me error "The sequence contains no elements" even if all cells have a value and also because it seems to be written only for string fields.
At the moment my knowledge isn't enough to successfully edit this code so to adapt it to my needs.

2) The 2 answers that suggest to use `MaxLength` don't give me what I need because I need the current Length of each column and not the maximum allowed length.

Thanks to all for helping

So here's the code I used:

```vb
Dim MaxColLen As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
For y As Integer = 0 To DT.Columns.Count - 1
    Dim Col As String = DT.Columns(y).ColumnName
    MaxColLen.Add(Col, 0)
    For x As Integer = 0 To DT.Rows.Count - 1
        If DT.Rows(x)(Col).ToString.Length > MaxColLen(Col) Then
            MaxColLen(Col) = DT.Rows(x)(Col).ToString.Length
        End If
    Next
Next
```