# How to get Min String Length, Greater Than 0, in every Column of a Datatable

Tags: .net, datatable, min

I checked this page already = [How to get Max String Length in every Column of a Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053560/how-to-get-max-string-length-in-every-column-of-a-datatable)

I have a .NET DataTable (loaded from flat files, 50+ columns, 500K records). All columns are String type. Column can have NULL or Empty value. I want the Min Length of each column of the datatable where Length>0 (excluding the NULL or Empty values ).

in SQL the query would be (for single column) = select MIN(LEN(Field))  [MinLen] from MyDataTable where len(Field) > 0

I can run "foreach DataColumn" and get individual column's MinLength but takes time. Would like to get all the MinValues > 0 in one shot, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: [How to get Max String Length in every Column of a Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053560/how-to-get-max-string-length-in-every-column-of-a-datatable) should get you there. Otherwise try something and post a concrete problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hey, this is solution:**

```
private void AddNullAllowedColumn()
{
    DataColumn column;
    column = new DataColumn("classID", 
        System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    column.AllowDBNull = false;// this is solution

    DataTable table;
    table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add(column);
}
```